# How to end the sub process when using subprocess.Popen with python?

Tags: python, popen

I use a script to run two script. the code like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("python a.py", shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("python b.py", shell=True)
```

but if I end the main script, the sub process of a.py and b.py are still runing. How to solve it?

added:

the a.py and b.py is two server scripts. When I end the main script using ctrl+c,and the two servers is not end up.So how to end the all process when I end the main script?

Comment: Try popen(“kill $!”, shell=True) though that would only kill last one and the answer below is better

Comment: You do not need `shell=True`, you are only introducing a security risk with that. Just do `Popen(['python', 'a.py'])`. `shell=True` is useful only when you are using some shell feature (e.g. pipes/redirection/built-ins/expansions etc) and even most of those can actually be avoided. If you are just running an executable do not specify `shell=True`.

Comment: Have any reason to start a new python interpretor instead of simply calling `import a.py` or at least `compile` and `exec`?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta If I using shell=False, it give me an error:No such file or directory: 'python a.py'.

Comment: @XiaXuehai You should use `Popen(["python", "a.py"])` not `Popen("python a.py")`. Or if you don't want to manually write the least do : `import shlex` and then `Popen(shlex.split("python a.py")))`

Answer (score 3):

By killing the processes.

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen("python a.py", shell=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("python b.py", shell=True)

# ... do things ...

p1.kill()
p2.kill()
```

You can also automate this with the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module:

```
import subprocess
import atexit

p1 = subprocess.Popen("python a.py", shell=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("python b.py", shell=True)
atexit.register(p1.kill)  # register for killing
atexit.register(p2.kill)

# ... do things ...
```

Comment: THX, but the a.py and b.py is two server scripts. When I end the main script using ctrl+c,and the two servers is not end up.So can you tell me how to end the all process when I end the main script?